# GtkTextView can't wrap line

Tags: c, gtk, gtktextview

Hello I'm using Gtk on C, I need to have a GtkTextView in the middle of my window with many other widgets, I can't make the widget wrap lines. This is a very annoying behavior, anyone have any idea of what am I missing? This is the code I'm using to set it's properties:

```
gtk_text_view_set_left_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(commentsTextView),20);
gtk_text_view_set_right_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(commentsTextView),290);
gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(commentsTextView),GTK_WRAP_WORD);
gtk_text_view_set_pixels_inside_wrap(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(commentsTextView),0);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(commentsTextView,300,300);
```

Edit:

I solved this in a different way, still the problem remains unsolved :S

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: I looked over the source code and I wasn't able to find anything related to this issue. This was a while ago so I can't quite remember what the workaround was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your text view into a `GtkScrolledWindow`?

Comment: No, I didn't. That wasn't the behavior I was looking for. Anyway thanks for the answer, I ended up solving it in another way. Sorry I never replied :S

Comment: This is probably not what solves the problem but it indeed helps to attack it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure there are spaces in your text if you want the wrapping to occur on words. If there are no spaces in your string that is inserted into the text view gtk won't know where 1 word ends and the other begins.

If you want the text to wrap on a string without spaces you could use `GTK_WRAP_CHAR` in place of `GTK_WRAP_WORD`.

Comment: You can also use `GTK_WRAP_WORD_CHAR` (in Vala, `Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR`) which might be closer to the behaviour you’d normally want (break at word boundaries if possible and, only if not, break between grapheme clusters).